# How to check for the existence of a certain file or files under certain file system path?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a path and want to check if there is a file or an image saved in the Project under that path.

Is this possible to do in Node?

Comment: This is not a Typescript question. More appropriate tags would be`javascript` and (presumably)  `node.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a glob search library such as [fast-glob](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob#readme)

For example, this will find all Markdown files at any depth below the `docs` dir in your project:

```
const fglob = require('fast-glob')

const matches = fglob.sync( 'docs/**/*.md')

console.log(matches)
```

Replace the glob pattern to suite your needs.